# Is there a way to open TexMaths equations (.odt) in MS word?

Tags: msword

For the purpose of collaboration, I use LibreOffice with TexMaths.

The vast majority of collaborators use MS Word 2007, so I am forced to save into .docx so that they can read the equations and edit the text (but not edit equations, they are saved as images).

If MS Word opens the .odt file directly then the equations appear as jibberish.

Is there some easy extension or equivalent that I can tell them to install if they want to edit my equations and then pass them the .odt document?

Comment: Sorry, but looks off-topic. There is no TeX involved here: neither MS Word nor LibreOffice uses any TeX code.

Comment: @JosephWright: [TexMaths](http://roland65.free.fr/texmaths/) is a LaTeX equation editor plugin for LibreOffice. I believe that there should be users on this site who have faced the same question... (and would argue that it falls under the site scope of "related software and tools")

Comment: 'LaTeX' in the sense you mean is the TeX-like math input syntax, rather than a full typesetting system. Like MathJax, the issue with this is that it's never _quite_ TeX.

Comment: @JosephWright: It is the full typesetting system in that it relies on an installed TeX distribution and compiles an article document to extract the formula; I can even use `\end{equation}` in the code and then start my own LaTeX document sections etc within the equation space.

Comment: OK, that would make questions about itself TexMaths on-topic (worth knowing), but Word handling of `.odt` files really isn't. This comes down to (1) how the data is stored in the `.odt` file and (2) what Word then decides to do with it. Neither of those things is TeX-related.

Comment: OK, I reposted the question at http://superuser.com/questions/755446/is-there-a-way-to-open-texmaths-equations-odt-in-ms-word.